# Producing a matrix class that supports any size

Tags: scala, matrix

I'm doing exercise 11.8 from Scala for impatient, asking to write a matrix class:

> Provide a class `Matrix` - you can choose whether you want to implement 2
>   x 2 matrices, square matrices of any size, or m x n matrices. Supply operations + and *. The latter should also work with scalars, for example mat * 2. A single element should be accessible as `mat(row, col)`.

The code is working, but may be there can be improvements to make code more functional or more stable:

```
class Matrix(val n: Int, val m: Int, fun: (Int, Int) => Double) {
  private val matrix = Array.tabulate[Double](n,m)(fun)  

  def +(another: Matrix) = { 
    if (n != another.n || m != another.m) 
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sizes of arrays don't match.") 
    else 
      new Matrix(n, m, (i, j) => this(i)(j) + another(i)(j)) 
  }
  def *(another: Matrix) = { 
    if (m != another.n)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sizes of arrays don't match.")
    else  
      new Matrix(n, another.m, (i,j) => { var sum = 0.0; 
                                          for (k <- matrix(i).indices) sum += matrix(i)(k) * another(k)(j); 
                                          sum } 
      ) 
  }
  def *(k: Int) = new Matrix(n, m, k * matrix(_)(_) )

  def apply(i: Int)(j: Int) = matrix(i)(j)

  override def toString = { 
    var result = ""
    for (row <- matrix) {
      for (value <- row)
        result += value + "  "

      result += "\n"
    }
    result
  }
}
```

Comment: It's curious how you use a function as part of the constructor parameters. Is that proposed by the book? If so, could you give more details? If not, then I think you went the wrong way. No clue why the `tabulate` is in there either, and I'm not sure if it's something the book said that you didn't mention, or something you came up with for reasons I don't understand.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I updated the question. No, it was not part of task, I used it by myself. What's wrong with function in constructor and tabulate, could you please explain? May be Array in constructor would be better, I just decided that it's quicker to generate values with function, than create 2-dimensional array.

Comment: There should be a way to update individual values in the matrix, I think. The use of the function is clever, but won't work if you are allowed to update (create a new matrix with updated) individual values. I suggest you redo the problem with that additional (implicit?) requisite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all `var`. Doesn't the book show `for...yield` by that point? For example:

```
(i,j) => { 
  var sum = 0.0; 
  for (k <- matrix(i).indices) sum += matrix(i)(k) * another(k)(j); 
  sum 
}
```

Can be replaced with:

```
(i,j) => (for (k <- matrix(i).indices) yield matrix(i)(k) * another(k)(j)).sum
```

The `var` on `toString` can be replaced by using `mkString`. I'll let you work out for yourself how to do that, now that I called your attention to that method. And, yes, it that method works on `Array` as well, though it doesn't appear on Scaladoc for Scala up to 2.9.2 because it is added implicitly. I suggest you use the [nightly scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html) to look things up -- the documentation there is better, though it may show things not available on release versions, and so is the tool itself.